# Undefined HTTP GET Request Interpreted by Node.js Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, get-request

I am having an issue with my Node.js application where I am sending an http get request through an ajax call client-side, I am then receiving the request server-side, and trying to use the data sent through the get request. My issue is that the server says that the request is undefined. I have absolutely no idea why this is the case as I am doing other similar requests on other pages and they work fine.

Here is my error message:

```
/var/www/html/AdminExtension/extension/extension/node_modules/find/index.js:35
          throw err;
                ^
Error: ENOENT, lstat '/path/to/project/undefined'
```

The "undefined" bit is what is supposed to be the rest of the path retrieved from the request.

Here is my relevant app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var MemoryStore = require('connect').session.MemoryStore;

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3333);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view options', {layout: false});
app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
app.use(require('body-parser')({ keepExtensions: true}));
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: '12345678910', store: new MemoryStore({ reapInterval: 600000}) }));
app.use(require('method-override')());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        next();
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    next();
});

// Routes for browsing directories and listing contents
var browse = require('./routes/general/browse');
app.get('/browse/file/info', browse.getFileInformation);

app.listen(app.get("port"));
```

Server-side browse.js code:

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.getFileInformation = function(request, response) {
    var filePath = "/folder1/folder2/" + request.body.filePath;
    console.log('*' + filePath + '*');
    checkFileInfo(
            filePath,
            function(err, fileInfo) {
                if (err)
                    console
                            .log("An error has occured when trying to retrieve the file information: "
                                    + err);
                else
                    response.send(fileInfo);
            });
};

function checkFileInfo(filePath, callback) {
    fs
            .lstat(
                    filePath,
                    function(err, stats) {
                        if (err)
                            return callback(err);
                        else if (stats && stats.isFile()) {
                            var fileInfo = {};
                            fileInfo.size = stats.size;
                            fileInfo.created = stats.ctime;
                            fileInfo.modified = stats.mtime;
                            fileInfo.accessed = stats.atime;

                            callback(null, fileInfo);
                        } else
                            return callback("The path provided did not lead to an accessible file.");
                    });
}
```

And the client-side ajax request:

```
var obj = {
    filePath : "/relative/path/this_is_a_file.txt"
};

$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : serverUrl + '/browse/file/info',
    data : obj,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(fileData) {
        // Do something else
    }
});
```

I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I needed to use

```
request.query.filePath
```

instead of

```
request.body.filePath
```

Comment: I think you should also take a look at my updated answer - when you upload a file you should use POST instead of GET.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably in your `checkData` function:

```
function checkData(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body));
    return data;
}
```

It receives only data and you use the `request` object - it's not accessible in its context.

You can add another parameter called `request` to that function:

```
function checkData(data, request) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body));
    return data;
}
```

And send it the request object:

```
checkData(request.body.filePath, request)
```

**UPDATE**

After you've updated your question your original problem appeared.

I geuss the undefined problem you got there is because you're accessing the request body - a request has a body with parameters if it's a `POST` request (`GET` requests has only a url and headers).

Try changing your client side ajax call from `type : "GET"` to `type : "POST"` and update your nodejs:

```
app.get('/browse/file/info', browse.getFileInformation);
```

to

```
app.post('/browse/file/info', browse.getFileInformation);
```

I would also recommend to get a file path with `__dirname + '/path'` to avoid problems.

Comment: You are right. I did make a mistake there. However, I only just recently added that function and the problem still remains. The purpose of the function was to try to figure out what was inside request (though it is still undefined). The trace is a little different now though. Thanks for the extra pair of eyes.

I updated the question.

Comment: Are you sure you've updated your question? I'm looking at it and see the exact same stack trace that leads to the problem in checkData.

Comment: I wrote the comment before I edited the question. It should be good to go now. XD